# Uploading excel in to SQL Server in ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, excel, file-upload

When I try to upload an Excel sheet of data into SQL Server I get the following error first time it uploads well when I try to upload it shows the following error

Before uploading I am deleting files in the directory

```
string[] filePaths1 = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@"Excel\"));

foreach (string filePath1 in filePaths)
    File.Delete(filePath1);
```

The process cannot access the file

> 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\xyz.com\httpdocs\newofficework\Excel\super.xlsx'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be performing multiple actions here  (1) Delete and then (2) Upload

How are you Uploading the files?  If you are using the SaveAs method, then please ensure that you Dispose the same.

E.g. (fuExcel is my FileUpload control)

> ```
>         fuExcel.SaveAs(sUniqueFilePath); // string variable containing file path
>         fuExcel.Dispose();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The Page having a FileUpload control and the Upload button, on selecting the Excel file user needs to click on Upload button to store the data to Server. Here we are treating the uploaded file as database hence we need to create OLEDB connection to this file, from this connection will be created and the data is fetched to C# as DataTable. '[Sheet1$]' is the Name of the Worksheet where requires data is present.

```
string SourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" +  + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr);
string query = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
data.Fill(dtExcel);
```

From this code connection will be created for the Excel file and the data in Sheet1 will be dumped to the dtExcel of type DataTable. 
Note:'$' must be there after the worksheet name.

```
fileName = FileUpload1.ResolveClientUrl(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
int count = 0;
DataClassesDataContext conLinq = new DataClassesDataContext("Data Source=server name;Initial Catalog=Database Name;Integrated Security=true");
try
{
   DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
   string SourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr);
   string query = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
   OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
   data.Fill(dtExcel);
   for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      try
      {
         count += conLinq.ExecuteCommand("insert into table name values(" + dtExcel.Rows[i][0] + "," + dtExcel.Rows[i][1] + ",'" + dtExcel.Rows[i][2] + "',"+dtExcel.Rows[i][3]+")");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         continue;
      }
   }
   if (count == dtExcel.Rows.Count)
   {
      <--Success Message-->
   }
   else
   {
      <--Failure Message-->
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
finally
{
   conLinq.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add these two name space in your class file

using System.Data.OleDb;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

Use following code

public void importDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath)

{ 

//Declare Variables - Edit these based on your particular situation

 string sSQLTable = "tDataMigrationTable";

 // make sure your sheet name is correct, here sheet name is Sheet1, so you can change your sheet name if have different

string myExcelDataQuery = "Select StudentName,RollNo,Course from [Sheet1$]"; 

try

{

//Create our connection strings

string sExcelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";



string sSqlConnectionString = "SERVER=MyDatabaseServerName;USER ID=DBUserId;PASSWORD=DBUserPassword;DATABASE=DatabaseName;CONNECTION RESET=FALSE"; 

//Execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table

string sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM " + sSQLTable;

SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(sSqlConnectionString);

SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlConn);

SqlConn.Open();

SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlConn.Close(); 

//Series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our SQL table

OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(sExcelConnectionString);

OleDbCommand OleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(myExcelDataQuery, OleDbConn); 

OleDbConn.Open(); 

OleDbDataReader dr = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();

SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sSqlConnectionString); 

bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable; 

while (dr.Read())

{

bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);

} 

OleDbConn.Close();

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

//handle exception

} 

}
```